# Can't change selectfield options - InCode

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Here is my select field. We can see that the options are  SI,American and Imperial

```
{
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                flex: 1,
                itemId: 'units_Selector',
                maxHeight: 50,
                label: 'Units',
                options: [
                    {
                        text: 'SI',
                        value: 'SI'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'American',
                        value: 'American'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Imperial',
                        value: 'Imperial'
                    }
                ],
                usePicker: false,
                listeners: [
                    {
                        fn: function(element, eOpts) {
                            var unit = Ext.getStore('configstore').last().get('Units');

                            this.suspendEvents();
                            this.setValue(unit);
                            this.resumeEvents();
                        },
                        event: 'painted'
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Here what I see when using my app...

[image: choices]

OUPS seems like SI is displayed has International?
FYI - International was the option's name I gave this option at first. I decide to change it but my app seems to disagree with me on this one ....

Here is a console.log() of my selectfield's options 
[image: consolelog]

And here is the funniest part, my code.js file to see that it does save to it correctly from sencha architect 
[image: select]

Would anyone know how to repair that problem...?

Comment: Did you try saving, building and previewing the app in your browser? Sometimes, refreshing the browser could help. Perhaps!

Comment: I saved, refreshed, clear cache, close and open architect, deleted architect. (hidden folder) and sencha. (hidden folder)  nothing worked yet.

Comment: What if you delete your js file? The application should crash, or it will prove that something is cached somewhere you don't suspect. And what do you get if you use another browser?

Comment: Try clearing the Local History for your site.  In the dev tools, go to Resources -> Local Storage, click on each of the "keys" for your site, and delete them.

Comment: I already deleted local storage has I used it to save the configs :P
I also tried to used safari and IOS simulator with no better results :S

Comment: Sadly if I deleted teh .js file i wont be able to test it anymore has the .js file contais lot of other views in it

Comment: What do you have in the 'configstore'? Does it have items including 'international'? Are you setting it anywhere with your selectfield?

Comment: Not anymore, and I deleted to config to be sure not to mix the old value with the new.
It's quite strange.

Comment: I though that if it was some saved value somewhere, erasing and rewritting the code would save the problem... it did not i'm still receiving the text and not the value...  :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is dumb...

Seriously, if you have multilanguage app... double check you aint modifing the value field -_-< when updating the language (text field).

found the problem by changing the itemId to something else to see who what changing the value of this select field. (Automaticly created an error and gave me a code line to find it)